# Add/Remove or Show/Hide drop down list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Basically I have 3 drop down lists for security questions. I have java script setup that will spring an alert when the box is changed. I need to know how to add/remove or show/hide an option. like if the first box selected option 1....remove option one from the other 2 drop downs as possible selections.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').append($('select options:gt(n)').detach());
```

Comment: this answer might be really useful, but it would help if you could explain what you're doing.